# Two reverse proxies on the same domain, diferent path

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure two different reverse proxies on the same machine with diferent paths. They are set to proxy SonarQube (localhost:9000/sonar) and Jenkins (localhost:8080/jenkins).

I'm trying to achive that calling to http://server.name/sonar, proxifys to http://localhost:9000/sonar.

I have two issues:

- Sonar is correctly proxified but on the callback url (clicking in the logo), will point to http://server.name, instead http://server.name/sonar. I have tried with the X-Forwarded-Host header (which should be also included in ProxyPreserveHost directive).
- Jenkins proxy is not working. It crashes with a 404.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.name/sonar
  ProxyPass /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar
  ProxyPassReverse /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar
  ErrorLog logs/sonar/error.log
  CustomLog logs/sonar/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

# VIRTUAL HOSTS
####################
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.name/jenkins
  ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
  ErrorLog logs/jenkins/error.log
  CustomLog logs/jenkins/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should put jenkins rule inside the first virtualhost, but you should add ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://<hostname>/jenkins  as described here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/reverse-proxy-configuration-apache/

Comment: Thank you, Lety. That's what I ended up using :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you define your Virtual Hosts.  ServerName does not understand /something, only domain names.

**Option 1** define domain prefixes.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sonar.server.name
    
    ProxyPass /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar/
    ProxyPassReverse /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar/
    
    ErrorLog logs/sonar/error.log
    CustomLog logs/sonar/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jenkins.server.name
    
    ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    
    ErrorLog logs/jenkins/error.log
    CustomLog logs/jenkins/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

You would then have to use http://jenkins.server.name/jenkins/ or http://sonar.server.name/sonar/.

---

**Option 2** like option 1, but without the /sonar or /jenkins which are not required anymore.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sonar.server.name
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/sonar/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/sonar/
    
    ErrorLog logs/sonar/error.log
    CustomLog logs/sonar/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jenkins.server.name
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    
    ErrorLog logs/jenkins/error.log
    CustomLog logs/jenkins/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Here, use http://jenkins.server.name/ or http://sonar.server.name/.

---

**Option 3** Keep one domain, no prefix and split on the /something

All in one Virtual Host.  Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.name
    
    ProxyPass /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar/
    ProxyPassReverse /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar/

    ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
    
    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Sadly doing it this way you loose the separate log files.  CustomLog is only applicable in the global server configuration or inside a VirtualHost.

Use http://server.name/jenkins/ or http://server.name/sonar/.

---

Finally ensure you load module mod_proxy_html along with the other proxy modules.

Comment: Thank you, Nic!

I ended up using the third one, as I am requested to use the same domain and different paths.

Even so, I cannot figure out why sonar is taking me to / when clicked, although I have setted up the serverBaseUrl.

Comment: Do you mean it does that still or are you wondering from your initial question?  You can modify the target URL in the ProxyPass directives for `/sonar` as required.  You can start a new question with this specific issue if you want (put lots of details, do not expect readers will have read that one as a preliminary).

Comment: Probably sonar use absolute url, it means that it is not designed to run behind proxy or it needs some additional configuration